# Matchall only retrieves 5 results into a collection

Tags: regex, powerapps

I am using powerapps to retrieve data back from a automate flow.

I have a HTTP request then getting the response back using a variable.

The varVersionHistory variable gives json as string:

```
{  "versionhistorymetadata": "{\"Version\":\"11.0\",\"ModifiedDateTime\":\"Wednesday, Mar 16, 2022, 5:44 PM\",\"ModifiedBy\":\"MG\",\"ChangeSummary\":\"MG changes\"};{\"Version\":\"10.0\",\"ModifiedDateTime\":\"Wednesday, Mar 16, 2022, 4:58 PM\",\"ModifiedBy\":\"DP\",\"ChangeSummary\":\"test\"};{\"Version\":\"9.0\",\"ModifiedDateTime\":\"Wednesday, Mar 16, 2022, 4:34 PM\",\"ModifiedBy\":\"DP\",\"ChangeSummary\":\"test\"};{\"Version\":\"8.0\",\"ModifiedDateTime\":\"Wednesday, Mar 16, 2022, 4:04 PM\",\"ModifiedBy\":\"DP\",\"ChangeSummary\":\"Add a comment v5\"};{\"Version\":\"7.0\",\"ModifiedDateTime\":\"Wednesday, Mar 16, 2022, 4:03 PM\",\"ModifiedBy\":\"DP\",\"ChangeSummary\":\"Add a comment v2\"};{\"Version\":\"6.0\",\"ModifiedDateTime\":\"Wednesday, Mar 16, 2022, 1:29 PM\",\"ModifiedBy\":\"DP\",\"ChangeSummary\":null};{\"Version\":\"5.0\",\"ModifiedDateTime\":\"Tuesday, Mar 15, 2022, 2:37 PM\",\"ModifiedBy\":\"DP\",\"ChangeSummary\":null};{\"Version\":\"4.0\",\"ModifiedDateTime\":\"Monday, Mar 14, 2022, 6:44 PM\",\"ModifiedBy\":\"DP\",\"ChangeSummary\":null};{\"Version\":\"3.0\",\"ModifiedDateTime\":\"Monday, Mar 14, 2022, 6:40 PM\",\"ModifiedBy\":\"DP\",\"ChangeSummary\":null};{\"Version\":\"2.0\",\"ModifiedDateTime\":\"Monday, Mar 14, 2022, 11:02 AM\",\"ModifiedBy\":\"DP\",\"ChangeSummary\":null};{\"Version\":\"1.0\",\"ModifiedDateTime\":\"Monday, Mar 14, 2022, 10:58 AM\",\"ModifiedBy\":\"DP\",\"ChangeSummary\":null}"}
```

I am trying to covert that into a collection. I have this code which is working but it only gives me the top 5 rows in a collection.

```
ClearCollect(colVersionHistory,MatchAll(varVersionHistory,"\{""Version"":""(?<Version>[^""]*)"",""ModifiedDateTime"":""(?<ModifiedDateTime>[^""]*)"",""ModifiedBy"":""(?<ModifiedBy>[^""]*)"",""ChangeSummary"":""(?<ChangeSummary>[^""]*)""\}"))
```

Can you please help in fixing this?
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you work directly on the json object instead of using a regex?

Comment: @PedroLobito I am not sure how to do to that

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
ClearCollect(colVersionHistory,MatchAll(varVersionHistory,"\{""Version"":""(?<Version>[^""]*)"",""ModifiedDateTime"":""(?<ModifiedDateTime>[^""]*)"",""ModifiedBy"":""(?<ModifiedBy>[^""]*)"",""ChangeSummary"":(?:""(?<ChangeSummary>[^""]*)""|(?<ChangeSummary>\w+))\}"))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DjmZaH/1).

Note the `"ChangeSummary":(?:"(?<ChangeSummary>[^"]*)"|(?<ChangeSummary>\w+))` regex part: now, it matches `"ChangeSummary":` and then either of the two patterns:

- `"(?<ChangeSummary>[^"]*)"` - `"` char, then any zero or more chars other than a `"` char captured into "ChangeSummary" group, and then a `"` char
- `|`- or
- `(?<ChangeSummary>\w+)` - any one or more word chars captured into "ChangeSummary" group

Comment: Hi, I am getting the following error when I copy and paste the code you provided. The error says "The provided regular expression is invalid: SyntaxError: Cannot use same name for multiple groups (?<ChangeSummary>"

Comment: @samronaldo309 Even if you add `(?J)` at the start of the pattern (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DjmZaH/2))? If it works the regex engine is PCRE, not .NET.